# Why does custom guard get logged out on page reload/redirect?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-session, laravel-guard

I created a new guard for logging in custom type of users. I can login users with `Auth::attempt('webguest')`, but login does not persist over page reloads. It works only when I use `web`-guard. See for example my two test routes:

```
Route::get('test1', function () {
    \Auth::guard('webguest')->attempt([ 
        'id' => 5,
        'password' => 2222
    ]);

    // here dump(\Auth::guard('webguest')->check()) shows true

    return \Redirect::to('/test2');
});

Route::get('test2', function () {
    return \Auth::guard('webguest')->check() ? "guest account logged in" : "guest not logged in";
   
   // dumps not logged in

});
```

My custom guard:

`config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'webguest' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'guests'
    ],

],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'guests' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Guest::class
    ],
]
```

Both Guest and User models extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable`.

How can I make login with the custom guard persist like with `web` guard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the root cause.
In my Guest model the "username" used for login is the id, and there was an overriden method in the model:

```
 public function getAuthIdentifier() {
            return $this->user->getKey();
 }
```

I removed it and added the following instead:

```
 public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'id';
    }
```

Now the custom guard works like a charm.